# How to draw values of an array inside the PaintEvent

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, point

I have got four arrays which are filled with X,Y,Vx and Vy values.

I want to plot them into the PaintEvent of a Picture Box. Whats the best strategy to do that?

I've tried to combine both X and Y values as well as Vx and Vy to a point via a for-loop, but since my values are double and points only work with int or float that was not an option!

```
 public Form1()
{
        InitializeComponent();



        double[] x = new double[100000000];
        double[] y = new double[100000000];
        double[] vx = new double[100000000];
        double[] vy = new double[100000000];

   for(int i=1; i<x.Length; i++)

   {
    //calculating my array values here
   }
}

 private void PictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        graphics z = e.Graphics;
        pen P = new Pen(Color.Black,3)

       //take x and y values of []double and combine both to a PointD 
         structure     


    }
```

Is this the best way to go about this or could you tell the PaintEvent that two arrays belong together, something along that line?
I really want to avoid another struct of PointD, so im searching for easier alternatives, which give me the desired accuracy!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I really don't know just what you want to do. 'Draw' how? Show an example! Where, which layout? Explain of show!

Comment: Ok so the values inside the X[] and Y[] represent a point on the x-axis and a point on the y-axis of the cartesian system. If you would draw a line through these points, the lines would meet up and create a point(x,y)!  It's the same with my array values, they need to be combined in order to represent a point(x,y).   Short example: x[0] = 1, y[0] =2.  As long as they are seperated the don't represent a point. But if you combine them like so Point(x[0],y[0]) they represent this point: Point(1,2). Hope this helps!

Comment: Why is converting to `float` or `int` a problem? Your screen has a finite resolution, so using `double` does not give you an advantage. Btw, drawing 100M points with GDI will most likely not work with interactive framerates. Even DirectX / OpenGL will probably not just work without some clever culling and/or level of detail.

Comment: Int is way to unprecise, float will just work for couple of orbits...should've said that im simulating orbital motions! I'm not really trying to plot all points at once, would like to plot them individually so they get replaced each time by a new one so it appears as a moving object!

Comment: look for polyline in your environment ...  you can interpret the points as lines or SPLINE/BEZIER control points but you got a lot of them and when using more planets it will be sloooow  so you should first select which points will be drawn (only those visible) ... anyway GDI or what you use now will be crushing you with speed limits so I suggest to use OpenGL or DirectX where you can move entire path and rendering into GPU ... you know VBO/VAO + LOD (level of detail) ... Another option is to fit several BEZIER/SPLINE cubics simplifying your huge dataset to just few points ...

Comment: btw you should write more background info into your questions as those who are not familiar with your recent questions have no clue what the dataset holds or represents etc ... The question should be self contained that means all the stuff needed to answer it must be in it no one will search all your older questions just to find out if the missing stuff is in them ... so for example in this case you should add that the arrays hold (time) ordered points representing trajectory and speeds of body along it in 2D space...